# Authenticate a user on Node.js + Passport + Polymer

Tags: node.js, polymer, passport.js, polymer-1.0

I have a backend based on Node.js + Passport (local) for authentication.

Now I want to login a user using a Polymer UI and access protected resources and endpoint. I have not found any example project on the internet ...

What are the necessary steps to authenticate a user over the Polymer UI and use the obtained token to access protected resources?

Comment: Authentication with the backend is orthogonal to any technology stack used on the client and thus there is nothing special about polymer compared to if you would use pure javascript regarding authentication. 
You can either post a form and retrieve an authentication token or use `iron-ajax` to do so.